# How to use flood fill for coloring a wall on Video Camera using OpenCV?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, video, flood-fill

I need to fill wall paint with real time video camera using flood fill, the below code results in a white layer on the image:

```
(void) processImage:(cv::Mat&)image
{ 
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Point seed(100,200);  
    cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    cv::floodFill(image, mask, seed, cv::Scalar(255, 10, 20) ,0, cv::Scalar(2,2, 2), cv::Scalar(2,2, 2), 4 );
    cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!.... Remove this conversion......

```
cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
```

Comment: Good work figuring out the problem! Maybe if you add some documentation that shows why this was a problem, it can help out others in the future! :)

Comment: Thanks.. There is no need to converts image from one color space to another because its add a color space on your semi-uniform image region which is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

You got converted image from `mask`

Try this

```
-(void) processImage:(cv::Mat&)image
{ 
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Point seed(100,200);  
    cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    cv::floodFill(image, mask, seed, cv::Scalar(255, 10, 20) ,0, cv::Scalar(2,2, 2), cv::Scalar(2,2, 2), 4 );
    // Now you will get converted image from 'mask'
}
```